# useEffect and Axios getting a null json

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I built a react code using `useEffect()`and Axios to get a json from an URL, however I'm getting an empty array, probably because it is not async function. Here is my code:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";



export function UseVacation (){
    const[vacations, setVacations] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() =>{

        axios.get('APILINK').then( async (res) =>{
            
            setVacations(res.data);

            console.log("vactest: "+ JSON.stringify(vacations))

        }).catch((err)=>{
            alert("Error extracting the data from API: "+err);
        })

    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            
                {vacations.map( (vac) => {
                    <h1>{vac._id}</h1>
                })}
            
        </div>
    )

}
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: It's mentioned in the official docs that invoking the state right after setting it doesn't guarantee the return of the updated state. That might be why you're getting the default empty array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed my return and it fixed issue. Why? I don't know, but is working:

```
return (
    <div>
        {vacations.map( (vac) => {
            return(
                <h1>{vac?._id}</h1>
            )
        })}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: in ECMAScript 6 when you are using arrow function it adds return automaticly for example;



const dummyFunction=()=> {return a;} equals 
const dummyFunction=()=> return a ;

in your code 

 <div>
            
                {vacations.map( (vac) => {
                    <h1>{vac._id}</h1>
                })}
            
        </div>

in your map  you use "{" but no return value thats why its not working. Your map does not have return value.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you console res.data instead of vacations  and see what it has ? Also check the network tab, and see what actual request has in the response

Comment: I tried that and console shows data when consoling res.data

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
return (
    <div>
        
            {vacations && vacations.map( (vac) => {
                <h1>{vac._id}</h1>
            })}
        
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Same issue, looks like vacations State doesn't have data (that is why I was consoling the vacations)

Comment: Must be something the API then... are you able to get any data from the API? What do you get when you console.log(res.data)?

Comment: So when you log res.data you see the data in the console? You setVacations(res.data) so the data should be in vacations. Try console.log(vacations) just above your return statement. What do you get?

Comment: Looking at the axios docs I don't belive your .then call back should be async. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have good suggestion for you:

```js
const[vacations, setVacations] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  const getApi = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('APILINK')
      setVacations(res.data);      
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }                
  }
  getApi()
}, [])
console.log("vactest: "+ vacations)
```

I cannot explain but if you set state in useEffect and direct log state in useEffect, it only log previous state